# Is there a way to retrieve objects of a %Library.RelationshipObject by a certain order

Tags: objectscript

[This documentation](http://docs.intersystems.com/latest/csp/documatic/%25CSP.Documatic.cls?APP=1&LIBRARY=%25SYS&CLASSNAME=%25Library.RelationshipObject) has no mention of sorting the elements

Comment: Ex if objects are cars that have the following properties, color, make, model. I want to print out a list of objects ordered by color,

Comment: 1. Please provide class definitions. 2. %Library.RelationshipObject is not used directly 3. How do you access the data? Via objects? Please edit your question to address these points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an example I'll show sql query by class Sample.Employee in SAMPLES namespace, where properties Spouse and Company are relationships. You may get access to related object via `->` and you can order by alias.

```
SELECT
  title,
  Spouse->Name,
  Company->Name as CompanyName 
FROM 
  sample.employee 
ORDER BY
  CompanyName
```

Comment: Thanks DAiMor. But that objects I am dealing with do not have a %Id, so I do not know how to get them using a sql statement.

Comment: Why do you think so, why do you think it is so matter? Every table in Caché by default has %ID property.

Comment: When I do  "write object.%Id()", where object is the classname of the child or the parent,  on the terminal nothing is returned. %Id would are needed in the select statement to make sure I am selecting the rows of child objects that belong to the parent object.

Comment: Just update you question with simple example of you classes, parent and child. It helps to understand your problem.